# Wordpress Front Slider Plugin Fix

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, slider

The link to the plugin
http://www.iwebix.de/front-slider-wordpress-plugin/

This plugin has an auto slide option and the current active thumbnail showing up has a border.

The thumbnails are at opacity 0.7. I need the current active thumbnail to be at opacity 1.

Could some1 help me with this.

Not sure if I can post the entire .js code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Sorry I misunderstood your question. You do not have a whole lot of options here. You could edit the plugin, if you do leave a changelog of what you changed and why.

Or it might be worth trying to add some jQuery in a .js file in your theme. Something like:

```
jQuery("#fronter img").click(function() {
    jQuery("#fronter .active").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

And some simple CSS like:

```
#fronter .active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

And a tip, try your very best never to edit core files in WordPress or Plugin files. When it comes to updating it, it WILL overwrite any changes you made. Have a look at [Child Themes](http://op111.net/53/) and this is a good read about [plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30405/how-to-edit-a-wordpress-plugin-without-break-its-update-process)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam! I tried it but it makes all the thumbnails with opacity 1. I Just need the active thumbnail.If you look at this link http://preview.wp-themix.org/plugins/front-slider/ . On hover the image has opacity 1. I need it to be auto. When the image slides

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry I misunderstood your question.